# Which Javascript date format is compatible with all browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, date

ok, I just read like all articles on google about javascript date formats but I can't find one that is compatible with all browsers. Can someone give me a rock solid format that just works?

This is what I have been using so far. However, it does not work in Firefox 20.0.

```
var days = Math.floor((new Date() - new Date('2013-04-24T12:00:00Z')) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);

document.getElementById('days').innerText = days;
```

And then I am trying to display it in my HTML document like this:

```
<span id="days"></span>
```

Comment: This site might help -http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/. *Warning Browser support for this is inconsistent. Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers*.

Comment: ISO8601 format will be compatible like  `"Fri, 26 Apr 2013 13:00:14 GMT"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your date code, it runs perfectly fine.  It's just that Firefox does not support the `innerText` property.  Change the last line to the following:

```
var genericText = document.body.textContent ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
document.getElementById('days')[genericText] = days;
```

All newer browsers support the ISO 8601 date formatting standard when used in the specific applicable methods of `Date` ([reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)).  However, IE8 and below don't support the ISO 8601 format, as well as a few other legacy browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know

```
date = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
utctime = date.getTime() - (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()*60000;
utcdate = new Date(utctime);
```

Is supported by almost all the browsers(Includes <= IE8 as well)

Comment: What about a time zone? How to include that?